# zu and verb stem: written together or not?

Tags: verb

Can anyone tell me if zu is written together in the same word with the stem, as in 'zudenken' for example or if there should be a space between the two words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is written as a separate word:

> Wir sind gekommen, um zu bleiben.

It is different however for separable verbs:

> Es wäre leicht gewesen, das nachzulesen.

Comment: Thanks. The context was 'nach zudenken'. Does putting nach before it make it run together into one word?

Comment: Yes, *nachdenken* is separable: Ich denke nach. Therefore, *nachzudenken*.